# how can ı handle react with firebase authentication problem?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying develop user authentication page in react with firebase.
I can sign in but then sign in doesn't change to sign out.
what is the problem?

```
  
    const handleAuthentication = () => {
    if(user){
        auth.signOut();
    }
   }
```

```
  <div onClick={handleAuthentication} 
            className="header_option">
                <span 
                className="header_optionLineOne" >Hello, Guest</span>
                <span 
                className="header_optionLineTwo" >{user ? 
                'Sign Out': 'Sign In'}</span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the user is actually signed out, but the UI is not rerendering as it doesn't know about the change.

To fix this, you'll want to store the `user` in the component's state, with either `setState` or a `useState` hook:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  setUser(user);
});
```

With the user being part of the state, the call to `setUser(user)` will cause the component to rerender and thus show the updated (lack of) user information.

Also see the first code snippet in the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-version-8).